# Unable to connect to Big Query using SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
project = 'my_project_id'
dataset = 'my_dataset'
service_account_file = "service-account-key.json" 
sqlalchemy_url = f'bigquery://{project}/{dataset}?credentials_path={service_account_file}'

print(sqlalchemy_url) #to check the url

engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_url)

requirements.txt contains the following
typing
SQLAlchemy==1.4.49
google-cloud-bigquery
google-cloud
python-dotenv
google-api-python-client
sqlalchemy-bigquery[bqstorage]
pybigquery==0.7.0
```

I get the following error

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tunes\TunesABC.py", line 21, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(sqlalchemy_url)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "D:\Tunes\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 375, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Tunes\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 560, in create_engine
    (cargs, cparams) = dialect.create_connect_args(u)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Tunes\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pybigquery\sqlalchemy_bigquery.py", line 335, in create_connect_args
    project_id, location, dataset_id, arraysize, credentials_path, default_query_job_config = parse_url(url)
                                                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Tunes\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pybigquery\parse_url.py", line 50, in parse_url
    credentials_path = query.pop('credentials_path')
                       ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'sqlalchemy.cimmutabledict.immutabledict' object has no attribute 'pop'*
```

Looks like this is a pybigquery and SQLAlchemy compatibility issue. Is there a way to solve this? Has anybody figured out the compatible versions?